# How to resolve error for Plaid API -"The type Callback is not generic; it cannot be parameterized ..."

Tags: java, plaid

I am trying to follow below from [Plaid Java API doc](https://github.com/plaid/plaid-java), but getting the error: "The type Callback is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments "

```
Basic Usage
// Use builder to create a client
PlaidClient plaidClient = PlaidClient.newBuilder()
  .clientIdAndSecret("your_client_id", "your_secret")
  .publicKey("your_public_key") // optional. only needed to call endpoints that require a public key
  .sandboxBaseUrl() // or equivalent, depending on which environment you're calling into
  .build();


// Synchronously exchange a Link public_token for an API access_token
// Required request parameters are always Request object constructor arguments
Response<ItemPublicTokenExchangeResponse> response = plaidClient.service()
    .itemPublicTokenExchange(new ItemPublicTokenExchangeRequest("the_link_public_token")).execute();

if (response.isSuccessful()) {
  accessToken = response.body().getAccessToken();
}
```

When I try synchronous I also get error: "Response cannot be resolved to a type"

```
// Synchronously exchange a Link public_token for an API access_token
// Required request parameters are always Request object constructor arguments
Response<ItemPublicTokenExchangeResponse> response = plaidClient.service()
    .itemPublicTokenExchange(new ItemPublicTokenExchangeRequest("the_link_public_token")).execute();
```

I have imported this folder structure from Eclipse and I am trying to create a main class within the attached image. I've tried to move the Main class to different areas and it does not resolve.

[image: Plaid API java project]

java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

Eclipse:
Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Plaid was able to help me understand my problem --

"We have some checkstyle rules that run as part of the maven compilation process to ensure that our SDK follows a specific format.

The main class that you added conflict with those rules, but that is because it is not intended to check out the plaid-java repo and add your code directly."

So, I should have followed their directions here:

**Installation**
Plaid-java is available at [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=plaid-java)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.plaid</groupId>
  <artifactId>plaid-java</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```